# Enumerating the inner dictionary using foreach

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries, and I can't seem to figure out how to do a foreach loop on in the inner dictionary.

My collection:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, User>>
```

So far I have:

```
foreach(User user in myDic[someKey]??)
```

Comment: But what exactly do you want to do? Loop through all elements in all dictionaries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nested foreach

```
foreach (var keyValue in myDic){
   foreach (var user in keyValue.Value){
     ....
   }
}
```

or a bit of linq

```
        foreach (User User in myDic.SelectMany(i => i.Value).Select(kv=>kv.Value))
        {

        }
```

ordered by UserName

```
        foreach (User User in myDic.SelectMany(i => i.Value)
                                   .Select(kv=>kv.Value)
                                   .OrderBy(u=>u.UserName))
        {

        }
```

Comment: How about ordering my User.Username for the win?

Comment: SelectMany projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable<T> and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence. Then we select the Value from each keyValuePair (which happens to be User)

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<int, User>> users in myDic) {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, User> user in users.Value) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: myDic[someKey] already returns a Value of type Dictionary<int, User>.  I think you should take out the "[someKey]".

Comment: Using myDic[someKey].Values would probably be cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(User user in myDic[someKey].Values)
```

Is the literal answer to your question; though I'd generally recommend the use of the `TryGet` method unless you're *certain* that `someKey` is in the Keys collection of your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this ?

```
    var myDic = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();
    foreach(var item in myDic)
        foreach (var subItem in item.Value)
        {
            Display(
                subItem.Key,    // int
                subItem.Value); // User
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//given: Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, User>> myDic

foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<int, User>> kvp in myDic) {
   foreach(KeyValuePair<int, User> kvpUser in kvp.Value) {
      User u = kvpUser.Value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = myDic.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).SelectMany(dic => dic.Values);
foreach(User user in users)
{
   ...
}
```